# Strange Threads behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

.Hi, I have some problem with wpf and threading, and I just can't understend what happaning here.

I have this event func

```
private void TaskActiveChangeClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //Do things...
   this.ChangeTask((sqTask)this.SelectionObject, (sqTask)this.SelectionObject);
   this.FindSelectionObject();
}
```

ChangeTask

```
private void ChangeTask(sqTask Old, sqTask New)
{            
    //Do things (update in mongoDB)...
    this.LoadTaskList();
}
```

LoadTaskList [`TaskListTable` is a DataGrid]

```
private void LoadTaskList()
{
    //Do things (query mongoDB and get List<sqTask>)...
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        TaskListTable.Items.Clear();
        foreach (sqTask task in TaskList)
        {
            TaskListTable.Items.Add(db);
        }
    }                
    ));
}
```

**And now the weird part...**

The `SelectedIndex` binding to `TaskListTable` DataGrid (`SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"`)

**When I Run FindSelectionObject() just like this:**

```
private void FindSelectionObject()
{
    this.SelectedIndex = TaskListTable.Items.IndexOf(((sqTask)SelectionObject));
    MessageBox.Show("");
    DataGridRow row = TaskListTable.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(TaskListTable.Items[SelectedIndex]) as DataGridRow;                        
    row.Background = Brushes.LightGoldenrodYellow
}
```

**it works perfectly, but if I remove the `MessageBox` it crash becuase `row` not contains instance**

I guesss that `LoadTaskList` adding the items to the DataGrid, but it dons't update until the call end.
therefor, `...ContainerFromItem(TaskListTable.Items[SelectedIndex]) as DataGridRow;` is empty.

But when I use the messageBox, it makes the thred do some "Tick" before it search the row in the table.

**Questions:**
Am i right? and how can I fix it? (btw, If you can add to the answer recommended guide for theads use i'll be glad)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is because while you show the box, the `TaskListTable` gets all its items added. If you put a dummy `Thread.Sleep` there instead, it would work.

Comment: Nope, it isn't, I tried.. btw, all of the functions happenings in the same thread... @It'sNotALie.

Comment: its still not working. and again: I think all of the calls is sync - there is no async threads here (just one thread), so thread.sleep just stop the whole process. @It'sNotALie.